# How can I display the currently selected settings in a panel?

Tags: python, panel

In my panel I have 3 buttons you can press. Each one will change the File format type to a different setting. I would like to add text above the buttons that displays "Current Selection:" and then what ever setting that is currently selected (for the File Format).

[image: Change the Cube to what ever setting that is currently selected/active]

By looking at the template I know this is possible, because you can add the name of the currently selected object.

`row.label(text="Current Selection: " + obj.name)`

I know the obj is related to the object in the scene but I need to know how to change it so I can display the File format type instead.

I just don't know the proper context to make it work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with it, I think it would be easier just to add this:

```
scene = context.scene
view = scene.view_settings
row.prop(view, "view_transform")
```

Not only do we get the options we want but we can see which is active.

[image: new layout]

Alternatively, as brockmann has said, you can use:

```
layout.prop(view, "view_transform", expand=True)
```

which would give you this -

[image]

Comment: You can pass `expand=True` to get all options at once: `row.prop(view, "view_transform", expand=True)`.

Comment: @brockman, that's helpful thanks! I will add it to the answer.. Thanks for the info.. I am not sure which I like better.. Both are good options..